# this commands fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2) show error UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python-unicode

I am running the following command in spyder,

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/hh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib_inline/backend_inline.py", line 41, in show
display(

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py", line 327, in display
publish_display_data(data=format_dict, metadata=md_dict, **kwargs)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/core/display.py", line 119, in publish_display_data
display_pub.publish(

File "/home/hh/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 138, in publish
self.session.send(

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 830, in send
to_send = self.serialize(msg, ident)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 704, in serialize
content = self.pack(content)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 95, in json_packer
return jsonapi.dumps(

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/zmq/utils/jsonapi.py", line 40, in dumps
s = jsonmod.dumps(o, **kwargs)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/**init**.py", line 398, in dumps
return cls(

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 296, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 378, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)

File "/home/hh/anaconda3/envs/gee/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 44, in encode_basestring
s = str(s, 'utf-8')

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte

Got the same error if I run the same code in jupyter lab. However, if I run the command on terminal, the fig, ax = plt.subplots() works fine.

This only happens recently and I didn't have this issue before. Checked online material, but didn't find a solution. appreciate if only can provide any insights. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem running plain jupyter and within vscode.
Try updating the jupyter installation incl. required libraries. In my case

```
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter_client pyzmq
```

fixed the problem.